# Gradle DSL method not found: 'destination()' after upgrading to gradle 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I cloned an android project from git and I was prompted by Android Studio to update my gradle version to 5.1.1, after that I got this error Gradle DSL method not found: 'destination()'. Please I need help.

I tried to return the version to gradle 4.10.1 and it builds succesfully but throws error at runtime DaggerApplicationComponet. I think Dagger auto generated file is failing at runtime so I'm hooked.

Comment: I finally got solution to this... 
I added 
`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` 
`kapt{
        generateStubs = true
    }` inside android{}
And I changed `annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21"` to `kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21"` 

inside gradle.build (app) 

I rebuild and boom, it worked without error